# Store function definition as a character object

Tags: r

Take the following example function

```
temp_fn <- function(){

    print("hello world")

}
```

I know that typing the function name without the parenthesis will return the function definition, that is:

```
> temp_fn
function(){

    print("hello world")

}
```

However, I can't figure out how to store what is printed out into a character object. For example

```
> store_temp_fn <- as.character(temp_fn)
Error in as.character(temp_fn) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Comment: the command `capture.output` seems promising, but this splits each line of the function definition into a vector entry, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `capture.output()` in combination with the function name like this:

```
temp_fn <- function(){

    print("hello world")

}

temp_fn_string <- cat(paste(capture.output(temp_fn), collapse = "\n"))

> temp_fn_string
function(){

    print("hello world")

}>
```

Comment: this however assigns each line to an entry in a character vector, which is not quite what I was after.

Comment: This works: `cat(paste(capture.output(temp_fn), collapse = "\n"))`

Comment: @Alex Please edit my question so that you may receive proper credit for the solution.

Comment: @Alex LOL I didn't know you were the one who asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another suggestion:

```
out <- as.character(getAnywhere(temp_fn)$objs)[[1]]
> out
#[1] "function () \n{\n    print(\"hello world\")\n}"
> cat(out)
#function () 
#{
#    print("hello world")
#}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
deparse(yourFunction)
```

Or

```
paste(deparse(yourFunction), collapse="\n")
```

if you want it as one big string.

Or, if you want to save it to a file

```
dput(yourFunction, "yourfile.R")
```